# Create dictionary comprehension from list with condition syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'd like to create a dictionary using dictionary comprehension syntax.

Note that list `l` contains tuples of strings and tuples with 1st element always a time stamp.

This works:

```
d = {}
for entry in l:
    if entry[0] not in d:
        d[entry[0]] = []
    d[entry[0]].append(entry)
```

This doesn't work:

```
d = {k[0].append(k) for k in l if k[0] in d else k[0]:k for k in l}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    d = {k[0].append(k) for k in l if k[0] in d else k[0]:k for k in l}
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This is doubly tricky because even if you get it into a syntactically valid form, you won't be able to do `k[0] in d` inside the statement that creates d, because d doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a dictionary comprehension for this. For each iteration step (if not filtered), a new key-value pair is produced. That means you *can't update another, already generated key-value pair*.

Just stick with the loop. You can simplify it with `dict.setdefault()`:

```
d = {}
for entry in l:
    d.setdefault(entry[0], []).append(entry)
```

Note that `d` in your example won't exist until the dictionary comprehension has completed; only then is `d` bound to the result. And more specifically addressing the syntax error, Python sees the part before the `:` as a separate expression to produce the key in the key-value pair, and the `for ... in ...` syntax there is being parsed as a generator expression (a form of comprehension syntax); you can use `if` in such an expression to filter, but there is no `else` part possible in a comprehension, hence the error pointing at `else` there.